# Race between observeEvent and update*Input when action button is rapidly clicked

Tags: r, shiny

**Background**

I have a shiny application for grading student work. The student's work is shown on screen and various buttons/checkmarks are used by the grader to assign grades. There is then a Next button to go to the next student (saving grades etc). There's also a Previous button to allow graders to review their grading history, thus each press of Next or Previous loads the existing grade for the student work into the buttons/checkmarks.

**Problem**

Unfortunately there is a race condition between updating the UI and moving to the next or previous student: The observeEvent() for Next for example first checks + updates the current student's grade (determined by the state of the buttons/checkmarks, or alternatively a reactive value) and then loads in the new student's current grades and updates the UI. Rapid presses of the Next button means that messages to update the UI can be delayed, and thus the state of the UI (or any reactives in which grades are stored) become updated based on old information from other students. This then is compared to the current student's grades and overwrites - not a nice situation. As long as the graders go slow enough on the "Next" button everything works fine ofcourse - it's just the speedier clickers that hit the fault.

**reprex**

The checkbox is filled from the `stored_checks` as you hit the Next button. If you hit Next in succession quickly enough, you'll get the "check has changed" message to the console, even though the status for that entry has obviously not changed as the checkmark button has not been pressed.

The reason is that `updateCheckboxInput` results in `observeEvent` being called on the checkbox, updating `vals$current`. Under rapid pressing of the `Next` button this updating gets out of sync (i.e. with a value from an earlier call to `updateCheckboxInput`) so that the `Next` button's `observeEvent` thinks the checkbox state has changed when it hasn't.

Note the 1 second sleep is just to make it easier to hit - essentially simulating slower updates (e.g. in our grading app we're loading up the student HTML or PDF work).

```
library(shiny)

stored_checks <- rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), 50)

ui <- fluidPage(
    checkboxInput("check", "Check"),
    actionButton("nextitem", "Next")
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
    vals <- reactiveValues(item=1, current=stored_checks[1])
    observeEvent(input$check, { # update this check
        vals$current <- input$check

        Sys.sleep(1) # simulated slowdown of other observers etc
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    observeEvent(input$nextitem, {
        if (vals$current != stored_checks[vals$item]) {
            cat("check has changed\n")
            stored_checks[vals$item] <- vals$current
        }
        vals$item <- vals$item %% 100 + 1
        vals$current <- stored_checks[vals$item]
        updateCheckboxInput(session, "check", value=vals$current)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any ideas most welcome!

Comment: One option would be to prevent people from clicking on the "Next" button too frequently, using `shinyjs::disable` for a fixed amount of time each time the "Next" button is clicked. However, this is not ideal since it may slow down the user.

Comment: Yeah - being able to flick through quickly is really useful. Thinking on it more, I'm convinced the design is the problem. A separate "Save" (and maybe a "Reset") button seems the way better way to go. It can operate like the "Next" button does (i.e. save and move on to next student to grade) but can be tailored such as highlighting it when a change is made, potentially disabling it based on shiny::isbusy which I *think* exists.